# Error while tokenizing strings from a string

Tags: c, getline, strtok

I want to generate a symbol table from a SIC Assembly code. For that I have tried to separate every strings form the assembly code. 
Hence while attempting first step for that, I tried this code.

**Here,
What I have tried is to read the assembly code form a file line by line. And then to separate the strings in the line to tokens.**

When I remove the token separation section (as mentioned in the code) I am getting all lines printed as expected.
But If I run along with token separation, the first line is getting read and the tokens are separated as I expected. But for the second line I am getting error as segmentation fault. 
I couldn't trace where I went wrong.

So, I need explanations form experts.

Thanks in advance.

> ```
>  FILE* sourceCode =  fopen("/home/muthu/LangFiles/SIC/PASS1/PROGRAM.txt","r");
>   if(checkForFileOpeningErrors() == ERROR)  //Iam using separate function
>       return EXIT_FAILURE;  //Terminate the program.
>   int maxLineLength = 50;
>   while(1)
>   {
>            char* lineReader = NULL;  // since getline will reallocate.
>        if( getline(&lineReader,(size_t*)&maxLineLength,sourceCode) == -1 )
>            break;
>        printf("%s",lineReader);
>
> // TOKEN SEPARATION STARTS HERE....   If I comment this section out iam getting all lines printed 
>             char* wordReader;
>       wordReader = strtok(lineReader," \n");
>       printf("%s\n",wordReader);
>       while(1)
>       {
>            wordReader = strtok(NULL," \n");
>            printf("%s\n",wordReader);
>       }
> // TOKEN SEPARATION ENDS HERE....
>   }
> ```

My FILE:

```
COPY START 1000  
FIRST STL RETADR 
CLOOP JSUB RDREC  
LDA LENGTH
COMP ZERO
JEQ ENDFIL
JSUB WRREC 
J CLOOP
.
.
.
END
```

My Sample output:

```
muthu@muthu-G31M-ES2L:~/LangFiles/PASS1$ ./a.out
All Files successfully opened!! Operation has begun...
COPY START 1000 

COPY
START
1000
segmentation Fault.
```

Comment: How is your `getline` function defined ? Note btw, that you seem to have a memory leak, since the `getline` function apparently allocates memory for the string, which never gets de-allocated.

Comment: And infinite loop inside an infinite loop.. _must go deeper_

Comment: Thanks all. I got the answer now. I went wrong in running the infinite loop only. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When do you expect this loop to terminate?

```
  while(1)
  {
       wordReader = strtok(NULL," \n");
       printf("%s\n",wordReader);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Uh, you're using `strtok()` wrong. It will return `NULL` when no more tokens are found, and you shouldn't try to print that. Also, your loop is never-ending, which will be a problem.

The loop should probably look something like this, since as-is now, you pass the same argument to `strtok()` on every iteration, which will of course never succeed:

```
for(wordReader = strtok(lineReader, " \n");
    wordReader != NULL;
    wordReader = strtok(NULL, " \n"))
{
   printf("found token: '%s'\n", wordReader);
}
```

Comment: could u explain me why not to print that. In strtok where i went wrong , how could i correct that.

Answer (score 0):

You never break out of the `while(1)` loop, so it tries to go on forever, but causes a segmentation fault when `strtok` returns `NULL`.

You need to check whether `strtok` returns `NULL`, and break out of the loop at that point.